# Tomcat clustering: The applications with no <distributable/> tag in web.xml are being clustered

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, mod-jk

I have a cluster of two tomcat workers with one Apache 2.4 loadbalancer.

It works fine.

But I'm facing very strange problem.

My both workers are similar to each other. With the same set of applications. Those which come with tomcat itself. And one - my own. I used the same war to deploy on both workers.

The only difference between workers is that one is on Win7 machine and the other is on CentOS.

While CentOS worker starts it tries to cluster only one my  webapp which marked as **distributable/** in web.xml.

When Win7 worker starts it tries to cluster ALL webapps with no regard
to **distributable/** tag in web.xml.

I have no idea why Worker2 to cluster apps with no **distributable/** tag in web.xml.

Comment: What do you exactly mean while you say `"it tries to cluster"`? Do you mean Tomcat tries to replicate sessions from the other node in the cluster?

Comment: INFO: Starting clustering manager at /host-manager

Comment: 19, 2017 4:25:18 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool getBufferPool
INFO: Created a buffer pool with max size:104857600 bytes of type:org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool15Impl
юъЄ 19, 2017 4:25:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager getAllClusterSessions
WARNING: Manager [localhost#/host-manager], requesting session state from org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://161.10.230.122:4006,161.10.230.122,4006, alive=0,id={0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]. .

Comment: This operation will timeout if no session state has been received within 60 seconds

Comment: I don't need application host-manager  to work in claster